# i386 movsxw instruction in x86_64

Tags: macos, assembly, clang, x86-64, att

I am trying to compile Apple's Libm ([version 2026, tarball here](http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/Libm/)). The only file that is failing to compile properly is `Source/Intel/frexp.s` because

```
/<path>/Libm-2026/Source/Intel/frexp.s:239:5:
error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'movsxw'
    movsxw 8+(8 + (32 - 8))(%rsp), %eax
    ^~~~~~
/<path>/Libm-2026/Source/Intel/frexp.s:291:5:
error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'movsxw'
    movsxw 8(%rsp), %eax
    ^~~~~~
```

Looking around on the Internet I can only find very scanty details of the movsxw instruction but it does appear to exist for i386 architectures. I am running OS X 10.9.3 with a Core i5 processor. The macro `__x86_64__` is predefined, however it seems the `__i386__` macro is NOT *****.

I was under the impression that the x86_64 instruction set was fully compatible with the i386 set. Is this incorrect? I can only assume that the `movsxw` instruction does not exist in the x86_64 instruction set, thus my question is: what does it do, and what can I replace it with from the x86_64 instruction set?

*Checked with: `clang -dM -E -x c /dev/null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical at&t syntax for `movsxw` is `movswl` although at least some assembler versions seem to accept the former too.

Comment: So just to confirm, they are identical instructions, but as Intel syntax isn't accepted I should replace all `movsxw` instances with `movswl`?

Comment: `movsx` is the intel syntax (for all sizes), `movswl` is the canonical at&t syntax (for word to long), and `movsxw` is a strange mix of the two that I have never heard about but my assembler accepts it and creates the same instruction.

Comment: Ah I'm with you. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
movsxb : Sign-extend a byte into the second operand
movsxw : Sign-extend a word (16 bits) into the second operand
movsxl : Sign-extend a long (32 bits) into the second operand
```

`movsxw` assembles just fine for me in 64-bit mode using gcc/as (4.8.1/2.24). I don't have clang for x86 installed on this machine, but you could try specifying the size of the second operand (i.e. change `movsxw` to `movsxwl`, which would be *"sign-extend word into long"*).